# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 Connection string with SSL doesn't work

Tags: excel, ssl, connection-string, oledb

I have a application in which I am fetching an Excel Sheet from a server and edit/add data into it and save it. It was working fine when I didn't add a SSL but since I have added a SSL it stopped working and giving an error on

```
con.open();
```

My connection still look like this.

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\"";
```

Error looks like this

> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
>
> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
> at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
>
> at
>   CSNY_timelog.Controllers.ReportController.GenerateReport1(ReportViewModel
>   objviewmodel) in c:\Users\Arpan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\CSNY_timelog\CSNY_timelog\Controllers\ReportController.cs:line
>   939

Does any one know how to fix this issue?
Do I have to add more option in connection string to make it work?

Comment: If you want to know about Excel connection string alternatives you can use this [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/).

Comment: I read that and understand the Connection string , and its working fine when i dont include the SSL on the domain. but when i add the SSL on the domain , its not working.